# Get the max number in a varchar column SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, numbers, integer, max, varchar

I have a `varchar` column which holds comma separated numbers.
I want to fetch the max number in that column.

```
+-------------------+--------------+
| reference_no      | Name         |
+-------------------|--------------+
| 17530, 20327      | John         |
| , 14864           | Smith        |
| 8509              | Michael      |
| 14864, 17530      | Kelly        |
+-------------------+--------------+
```

So, in the above column (reference_no) example the output should be 20327.

Then I have to select the row which contains this number.

Comment: Can you fix the data first? There's no query that will be efficient with this sort of data!

Comment: Normalize your data--for now you'll need to use a [string splitter](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

Comment: I am using below query to normalize it but its not giving the desired output.

select substring(reference_no,charindex(',',reference_no)+1,len(reference_no)-charindex(',',reference_no)), reference_no from table_name

Answer (score 0):

Assuming NOT 2016+

If you have no more than 4 values in `reference_no` in any particular row, then perhaps `parsename()`

If more than 4, you may need to fix the data or use a split/parse function.

**Example**

```
Select MaxValue = max(V)
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (replace([reference_no],',','.')) ) B(S)
 Cross Apply ( values (try_convert(int,parsename(S,1)))
                     ,(try_convert(int,parsename(S,2)))
                     ,(try_convert(int,parsename(S,3)))
                     ,(try_convert(int,parsename(S,4)))
             ) C(V)
```

**Returns**

```
MaxValue
20327
```

Comment: reference_no column has more that 20000 values.

Comment: i am using below query but its not giving the right output.
select substring(reference_no,charindex(',',reference_no)+1,len(reference_no)-charindex(',',reference_no)), reference_no from table_name

Comment: @ArunkumarYadav In the sample data, is this 4 rows or 1 with 6 reference_no's ?

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
declare @tab table (reference_no varchar(max), [Name] varchar(100))
insert into @tab
select  '17530, 20327','John'    union
select  ', 14864     ','Smith'   union
select  '8509        ','Michael' union
select  '14864, 17530','Kelly' 

create table #final (val int)

insert into #final
    SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String
    FROM  (SELECT reference_no reference_no,  
            CAST ('<S>' + REPLACE(reference_no, ',', '</S><S>') + '</S>' AS XML) AS String  
        FROM @tab) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/S') AS Split(a);

select * from @tab where reference_no like '%'+ (select convert(varchar(100), max(val)) from #final) + '%'
drop table #final
```

Comment: There is no need to use a loop here.